# Can't draw lines in GooCanvas

Tags: perl, canvas, gtk

In a Perl/Gtk3 script and using GooCanvas, I can easily draw a rectangle, or an ellipsis, or whatever, but it seems to be impossible to draw a simple line.

Lines are drawn with a call to Goo::CanvasPolyline->new(). The line's coordinates a specified by a call to Goo::CanvasPoints->new(), but that call creates the following error:

```
GLib-ERROR **: ../../../../glib/gmem.c:105: failed to allocate 18446744069314558208 bytes at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/Glib/Object/Introspection.pm line 67.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've tried the Perl module Goo::Canvas and the more modern GooCanvas2; both produce the same error.

I wasn't able to find any working code examples; merely the non-working script below, which Google found on $RANDOM_WEBSITE.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 -init;

Glib::Object::Introspection->setup(basename => 'GooCanvas', version => '2.0', package => 'Goo');


my $window = Gtk3::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->signal_connect('delete_event' => sub { Gtk2->main_quit; });
$window->set_size_request(640, 600);
$window->set_title("Gtk3 GooCanvas with Perl Gobject Introspection");
$window->signal_connect(destroy => sub { Gtk3->main_quit });

my $swin = Gtk3::ScrolledWindow->new;
$swin->set_shadow_type('in');
$window->add($swin);

my $canvas = Goo::Canvas->new; # Gobject Introspection of Gtk3 Goo version
$canvas->set_size_request(800, 650);
$canvas->set_bounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
$swin->add($canvas);
my $root = $canvas->get_root_item();

# first point set
my $pts_ref = [50,50,180,120,90,100,50,50];

my $points = Goo::CanvasPoints->new(
         $pts_ref,
         );

my $line = Goo::CanvasPolyline->new(
   'parent' => $root,
   'close-path' => 0,
   'points' => $points, #in Gtk2 could just use $pts_ref
   'stroke-color' => 'black',
   'line-width' => 3,
);


my $ellipse = Goo::CanvasEllipse->new(
   'parent' => $root,
   'center-x' => 20,  
   'center-y' => 20,  
   'width'  =>  +60,
   'height' =>  +60,  
   'stroke-color' => 'goldenrod',
   'line-width' => 8,
   'fill-color-rgba' => 0x3cb37180,
);


$root->translate(200,200);

$window->show_all();
Gtk3->main;
__END__
```

Comment: I couldn't not fix it because the polyline doesn't show no matter what I do, but I don't get the error you said.

Comment: Are you sure Goo::Canvas supports Gtk3 ?

Comment: clamp: Line 7 requires GooCavas " version => '2.0' ", which is apparently the correct one for Gtk3. In the script above, I have already tried replacing the Goo::Canvas module with the GooCanvas2 module, with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

> `my $points = Goo::CanvasPoints->new( $pts_ref );`

According to [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas2/stable/goocanvas2-GooCanvas-Types.html#goo-canvas-points-new) the constructor should take *the number of points* to reserve, not the reference to the points array. So you could try:

```
[...]
# first point set
my $pts_ref = [50,50,180,120,90,100,50,50];
my $num_points = (scalar @$pts_ref)/2;
my $points = Goo::CanvasPoints->new( $num_points );

# Set the points:
my $j = 0;
for my $i (0..($num_points -1)) {
    my $x = $pts_ref->[$j];
    my $y = $pts_ref->[$j+1];
    $points->set_point($i, $x, $y);
    $j += 2;
}
[...]
```